# Restricted Permutations appropriate?

Tags: mixed-model, model-selection, permutation-test, likelihood

I am currently extremely insecure about an analysis I am about to conduct. In short, I apply cluster permutation testing to test for the significance of single coefficients of primitive nested models. As a test statistic, I use log ratio tests.

Let's say I have a tone with three different levels. A quiet tone, a moderate tone and a loud tone. Moreover, I have 30 subjects. Subjects are unreliably warned which tone will come next by a visual cue, which also has three levels accordingly.

We want to test two hypothetical ways the cue could influence the perception of the tone. One would be a linear function of the cue, the other one would be a surpise function based on the cue. Specifically, the surprise function would signify a difference between the cue and the actual tone.

Using simple linear factors, we get following levels for each factor:

Tone      : 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
Cue       : 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 
Surprise  : 0 1 2 1 0 1 2 1 0

Stimulus Model: 
data ~ stimulus + (1|subject)

Prediction Model:
data ~ stimulus + cue + (1|subject)

Surprise Model:
data ~ stimulus + surprise + (1|subject)

If I test the surprise model vs stimulus model using a log ratio test, which levels should be permuted? Would it be appropriate to only test by permuting within each stimulus level? I base this assumption on ideas explained by  Howell (2009), specifically the part on "Edgington's approach -- Restricted permutation of main effects", where is stated that

"But Edgington would argue that if you don't have an interaction, your best model is Yijk = μ + Si. + M.j + εijk, which is an additive model--it does not have an interaction. (...) Edgington reasons that if this is now your model you don't have to adjust for an interaction. Therefore you can test Size by shuffling the data for each month separately between size categories, and then test Months by shuffling the data for each size among the month categories."

http://www.uvm.edu/~dhowell/StatPages/Permutation%20Anova/PermTestsAnova.html

Moreover, based on other answers, I think that the data should only be permuted within subjects.

If this approach is valid, it would be great if you could give me an explanation why this is allowed or prefered to a full permutation of all levels.

Thank you very much in advance.

Edward